# Sys files removed (rm -rf /*) help

Tags: linux, rm

Today I made a mistake by running:

```
rm -rf /*
0200:00/power/control': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/device:01/PNP0200:00/power/runtime_suspended_time': Operation not permitted
```

So now I can't use any commands even `reboot` will not work.

```
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# ls
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# ps x
-bash: /bin/ps: No such file or directory
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# cd
-bash: cd: /root: No such file or directory
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# umount /dev/sdb
-bash: umount: command not found
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# grub-install '(hd0)'
-bash: /usr/sbin/grub-install: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# fsck /dev/sda1
-bash: fsck: command not found
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# umount /home
-bash: umount: command not found
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# apt-get
-bash: /usr/bin/apt-get: No such file or directory
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# yum
-bash: yum: command not found
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# chmod ugo+w .
-bash: /bin/chmod: No such file or directory
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# grep -a -C 500 'known pattern' /dev/sda | tee /tmp/recover
-bash: grep: command not found
-bash: /usr/bin/tee: No such file or directory
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# init=/bin/bash
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# mount -rw -o remount /
-bash: mount: command not found
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# pwconv
-bash: /usr/sbin/pwconv: No such file or directory
root@HLCommunity12:/var/www# reboot
-bash: reboot: command not found
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, you've destroyed your system. Reinstall the OS and restore backups.

Comment: is there anything else to do ?

Comment: There may be some "undelete" utilities available, but at this point, using them would be more trouble and take more time than a reinstall / restore, especially considering you'll have to effectively undelete the entire system one file at a time.

Comment: @dev0L you can learn from your mistakes. From my experience I would recommend having a separate `/home` partition, so reinstalling an OS allows you to leave your files, but 1) it's too late for that and 2) it would probably not work in this case. And always remember about backups.

Comment: thx  MatthewRock & John